# Real time notification in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Hello i'm new with cakephp, and I just want to add a simple notification system for my website, I mean some sort of messaging between admin and users, I found after some research that I should use node.js or web-socket. Is there any plugin that I should add to my project? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am giving answer very late but you can try with this for your requirement.
https://github.com/bakkerij/notifier